# Hide a UIlabel after some seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nsinvocationoperation

I'm using this following code to hide a UILabel after some seconds. Unfortunately if the user close the view during the NSInvocation is in progress the app crashes

```
- (void)showStatusBarwithText:(NSString*)text{
    lblNotification.hidden=NO;
    NSInvocation* invoc = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[lblNotification methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(setHidden:)]];
    [invoc setTarget:lblNotification];
    [invoc setSelector:@selector(setHidden:)];
    lblNotification.text=text;
    BOOL yes = YES;
    [invoc setArgument:&yes atIndex:2];
    [invoc performSelector:@selector(invoke) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

}
```

and that's the error

```
 *** -[UILabel setHidden:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1a8106d0
```

How can I solve? I have tried using

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:lblNotification]
```

In the `- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you should use `performSelector`

```
- (void)showStatusBarwithText:(NSString*)text{
   lblNotification.hidden=NO;
   [self performSelector:@selector(hideLabel) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];//1sec
}


-(void)hideLabel{
  lblNotification.hidden= YES;
}
```

or with the timer

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1//1sec
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(hideLabel)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks, I like your solution. It keeps that so simple.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use `dispatch_afer`? The syntax is much more clear:

```
- (void)showStatusBarwithText:(NSString*)text{
    lblNotification.hidden=NO;
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        lblNotification.hidden = YES;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you pass `lblNotification` instead of `infoc` object here:
`[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:lblNotification]`

It will be better to do this way:

```
- (void)showStatusBarwithText:(NSString*)text{
    lblNotification.hidden=NO;
    lblNotification.text=text;
    [lblNotification performSelector:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:@(1) afterDelay:2];     
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated]
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:lblNotification];
}
```